# YouCompleteMe - the header completion doesn't work

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I tried using YouCompleteMe with a small C project. I ran ycm-generator, which yielded the following `.ycm_extra_conf.py`

```
flags = [
    '-x',
    'c',
    '-Wall',
    '-Werror',
    '-Wno-unused-function',
    '-Wno-unused-variable',
]
```

Unfortunately, the completion doesn't work as I'd expect:

1. When I type `#incl`, there is no "include" suggestion
2. When I type `#include <`, no standard C library headers are suggested

How can I fix it? You can see the whole `.ycm_extra_conf.py` here: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/99d1PFYl8Nz0SoEXf7iy/